# Plugin create a navigation menu

Tags: wordpress

How can I have a plugin (once installed) build a menu in the Appearance >> Menu area? I would like my plugin to make a menu called "office" and put 5 links on it. That way I can call that specific menu on a template the plugin installs.

Thanks in advance

PS I am not looking to build a menu item in the admin area. I want a navigation menu to be built in the APPEARANCE>>MENU area of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [**`wp_update_nav_menu_object`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L215) and [**`wp_update_nav_menu_item`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L278).

Check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39676/12615) WordPress Answers post for a working example.